# C# Dependency Injection : Retrieve a singleton to inject to other singleton constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I want to create a singleton which is based on another singleton that I created on the previous call. Here is the code:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPerson, Person>((ctx) => {
    WSPerson wsPerson = new WSPerson(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), new PersonRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options)));
    IMemoryCache memoryCache = ctx.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    return new Person(wsPerson, memoryCache);
});
services.AddSingleton<IEmployee, Employee>((ctx) => {
    EmployeeRepo employeeRepo = new EmployeeRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
    IMemoryCache memoryCache = ctx.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    // How to create instance of Person here, while taking the previous singleton added instead of creating another declaration of
    // WSPerson wsPerson = new WSPerson(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), new PersonRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options)));
    // Person person = new Person(wsPerson, memoryCache);
    return new Employee(employeeRepo, memoryCache, /* person */);
});
```

So in employee singleton, I need to declare an instance of Person that I've already added the singleton in the previous command.
How to pass the Person singleton without declaring another Person object inside the employee singleton custom constructor?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't register WSPerson, etc. with the container? If you could register all these classes that you're newing, then you could do away with most of this code.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do it properly. Previously it failed to do the dependency injection so that I have to declare it explicitly in the custom constructor.  Perhaps if you can help me it will great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolve the singleton via the provided `IServiceProvider ctx` in the factory delegate

```
//...

services.AddSingleton<IEmployee, Employee>((ctx) => {
    EmployeeRepo employeeRepo = new EmployeeRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
    IMemoryCache memoryCache = ctx.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    IPerson person = ctx.GetService<IPerson>(); //<-- gets the registered singleton
    return new Employee(employeeRepo, memoryCache, person);
});

//...
```

Assuming the two implementations depend on abstractions then make sure all dependencies are registered and avoid the factory delegate.

```
//...other dependencies assumed added to service collection 

services.AddSingleton<IPerson, Person>();
services.AddSingleton<IEmployee, Employee>();
```